# How to implement minimize button on modal popup in material core react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on react js application. I have implemented a modal popup with stepper in my app.
I want to add a minimize button on this modal popup. When we click on the minimize button it should minimize the popup anywhere below in the app window and on the click on that it should restore the popup in same size.

```
 <Modal
      aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
      aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
      open={open}
      
      onClose={handleClose}
    >      
     <div style={modalStyle} className={classes.paper} >
     {showCancel &&
     <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: 'flex-end', width: 'auto'}}>
     <IconButton onClick={handleClose}>
        <Cancel></Cancel>
      </IconButton>
      </div>}
     <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical"
     />
</modal>
```

Please help me with this.